# Do I get next season pass from DLC’s?

Tags: destiny-2

I am considering buying the Shadowkeep expansion, but saw that I get the season pass for free with it. So, should I wait the 18 days and get the season pass free? Or, should I get it now because it will carry over to next season, still free?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Season pass purchased are only available in the actual season, for the next season you will need again to buy season pass. So, it's better option to wait when the season is almost finished.